# Does commons-io's FileUtils.readFileToByteArray close the newly created stream?

Tags: java, io, apache-commons-io

I'm creating a program that produce checksums for each files in directory. I'm using `FileUtils.readFileToByteArray` which internally creates a new FileInputStream. The problem is I didn't find where the stream is closed and wondering about a possible memory leak.

So I'm asking: does this method close the stream after reading it?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray(java.io.File)

Comment: Apache is open-source, so look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/6efbccc88318d15c0f5fdcfa0b87e3dc980dca22/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java#L2199) of the method, and you will clearly see that the `InputStream` is in a try-with-resources statement, which means it is always closed correctly. --- Besides, as Dave Newton just indicated, the javadoc explicitly says *"The file is always closed"*. --- Question down-voted for lack of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it closes the stream.

Slightly longer answer:
Let's look at the code:

```java
try (InputStream in = openInputStream(file)) {
    final long fileLength = file.length();
    // file.length() may return 0 for system-dependent entities, treat 0 as unknown length - see IO-453
    return fileLength > 0 ? IOUtils.toByteArray(in, fileLength) : IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

That you see here is the [try-with resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax. Any [`AutoClosable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) opened in the `try`'s parentheses (in this case, a `FileInputStream`) will be implicitly closed when the `try` block terminates, whether it terminated normally or by `return`ing, throwing an exception, etc.